# htaccess file listing directory instead of using index.php

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I'm using nanoCMS (from mini-print.com) for website.
And htaccess file they provide.

Directory structure is -

```
cms/
  error404.php
  htaccess-laplume.txt
  htaccess.txt
img/
  readme.txt
```

while entering to `localhost/`,
I'm getting list of files instead of redirect to `/cms/index.php`

I cannot figure this out!
Can anyone suggest something to help?

(here is htaccess file)

```
# Edit and save this file as .htaccess before uploading
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ /cms/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms/inc/menu\.php$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms/inc/inmenu\.txt$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms/admin/list\.php$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.txt$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms/comments/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.txt$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/$

RewriteRule .* - [F]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cms/$
RewriteRule ^cms/$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /cms/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^cms/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /cms/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Is `/cms/` your document root? Is there another htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: No, cms is a folder in root folder

Comment: What is in your rewrite.log? Should be something like that:  `RewriteCond: input='/' pattern='^/$' => matched
rewrite '' -> '/cms/index.php'
internal redirect with /cms/index.php`

Comment: I can't start rewrite.logging - getting an error - .htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your htaccess file to the document root, otherwise, accessing `/` isn't going to touch anything in the `/cms/` folder.

Additionally, you need to make sure that the `AccessFilename` in your **httpd.conf** file is set to `htaccess.txt`. Otherwise, you can just rename your `htaccess.txt` to whatever the access filename is defined as. You should also make sure that you are loading your rewrite module, which should also be in your **httpd.conf** file and should look something like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure that line is *not* commented out.

Comment: htaccess file in root folder. but cms is folder inside root folder. and my index.php in cms folder. rewrite_module is working (i'm using it in other projects.